# Javascript DOM modification from Chrome extension disappearing

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I've written a Chrome extension that fetches my shopping list from a  recipe manager app's cloud service, and adds each ingredient to a supermarket's online shopping search page.

The website is Tesco Groceries, and I am using the "search with a list of items" page.

Thus far, I have managed to create the extension and write all the code. I have a popup with a button, which when pressed calls a content script. The content script makes a call to a background script which does the actual HTTP fetching via a jQuery ajax call, and passes the result back to the content script.

The content script then finally iterates through the result. 
The shopping list page is structured as a form, with each element appearing as

```
    <input class="multi-search-form__item-field" data-auto="multisearch-list-item" type="text" id="listItem3" name="listItems" placeholder="" maxlength="99" value="">
```

So I do

```
    for (index in json.result){
        selector = "#listItem" + index;
        $(selector).focus()
          .val(json.result[index].name)
          .attr("value", json.result[index].name)
          .change();        
    }
```

This actually appears to work, and all the correct text elements appear in the webpage. However, the submit button does not become active.

If I manually change (keyboard and mouse) any of the listItem text fields, all other text field inputs disappear, but the one I've edited remains. The submit button then becomes active.

I've noted that inspecting the HTML of the document shows that the value property of the automatically completed elements remains blank, but the manually changed one has the correct value.
I have tried using all sorts of combinations of setting .val, .attr("val", ), and using focus(), change(), and even trying to emulate a keypress of spacebar after the value has been input. Nothing works.

For example:
I have 3 items in my shopping list: milk, eggs and beans.
I open the webpage, click the button in my extension, and the webpage shows updated text fields with milk, eggs and beans each on its own line.
I then click in the text box with "eggs" in it, and press space. Now, the 2nd list box says "eggs ", but the other 2 boxes go blank.

Edit: As an additional note, if I just submit the form, that actually works, and the online shopping page appears with a result for my list. HOWEVER, The initial list only presents 10 text fields, and seems to dynamically add more once you begin typing in box 9. However, programatically filling that box doesn't cause it to make further text boxes, se my list caps out at 9 items.

Comment: Setting `.value` doesn't trigger the `onchange` event.  It has to be triggered manually.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event  I am assuming that existing JavaScript is listening to the `onchange` event; it could be another event, such as `onblur` or `onkeypress`.

Comment: Thanks. As mentioned above, I'm calling focus() and change(), to no avail. I've taken a peek inside the target site's javascript, and though it's obfuscated, I can see that it appears to have listeners for onKeyPress().